# Block Page Title Showing Up In Wrong Places - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, magento-2.1

I have a strange thing going on.  I have a module that adds a new page to the the site.  I have the block code's _prepareLayout() function setting the page title.  It works fine on the page, but that title also shows up on other pages.  The Wishlist, My Product Reviews, and also on our Blog's home page.  Its the Magefan Blog.

I thought it was a cache issue, but it is not.

Has anyone run into this issue, or can point me in the right direction?

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Garage'));
}
```

customer_account.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="account"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="customer_account_navigation_secondary" after="customer_account_navigation" template="Magento_Customer::account/navigation.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link-secondary"> <!-- duplicate this as many times as you need, just make sure the name is unique -->
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Garage</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">mygarage/vehicle/index</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Please, add your customer_account.xml file content to question

Comment: It has been added.

Comment: you need to create additional custom sidebar with link or add link to existing left menu (like as wishlist, Reviews)?